# valid Mosfet for Solar panel

Tags: mosfet, solar-cell

To protect a 3v/3w (mppt 3.2v/996mA) solar panel from back current (dark current) I would like to use a mosfet P-channel as it seems to limit voltage lost to 0.
Could you advice which one should I choose?
I have found the following one:
Drain-source voltage -16.5V 
Drain current -1.25A 
Power 1W 
Gate-source voltage -1V 
On-state resistance 1.5Ω 
Thanks in advance for your help 
Andrea

Comment: (1.5 ohms) (1 A) =1.5 V across the MOSFET. Why not use a power Schottky diode instead? You can probably find one with a forward voltage drop of about 0.5 V or less at 1 Amp forward current.

Comment: Thanks Jim, I didn't know there is such a drop, I don't understand why some call the mosfet a perfect diode. I will use the schottky diode even if planning to use a nimh 2.4v battery the solar panel will loose all its power to charge. Thanks anyway for your help

Comment: I would imagine that they call it a perfect diode because MOSFETS typically have zero voltage loss accross them when they are in active mode, we're with a diode you usually lose about .7 seven V sometimes more.

Answer (score 4):

The key to choosing a MOSFET as a switch is - *ignore* the current rating!

First decide how much voltage drop you can accept, and choose a FET with R<sub>DSON</sub> to match. For example if you want <= 0.1V drop at 1A then you need R<sub>DSON</sub> of 100mΩ or less. From this you can also calculate the FET's power dissipation, eg. 0.1V *1A = 100mW.

Next, make sure the Gate drive voltage is sufficient to turn the FET fully on. If you only have 3V available then look for a FET that is specified for 2.5V Gate drive.

Finally, ensure that the V<sub>GS</sub> and V<sub>DS</sub> ratings are at least 20% higher than the maximum voltages they may receive in your circuit.

The other thing to *ignore* is Gate threshold voltage. This is the voltage required to *just* start turning the FET on, and is poorly controlled so it may not turn *your* FET on at all!

To get an idea of required Gate voltage and expected voltage drop, look at the graph of I<sub>D</sub> vs V<sub>DS</sub> in the datasheet. Here's an example:-

[image]

You can see that at 3V (4th curve from bottom) it should drop 0.1V at ~2A. Note that as temperature increases so does resistance, so if the FET gets hot it will drop more voltage (and get hotter, and...). Therefore it pays to use a FET which is rated well above the actual current it is expected to pass.

Comment: Thank you very much Bruce, after several searches I have found this one that seems matching your recommendation. Thanks again Andrea.                 .        STMicroelectronics STN5PF02VP P-Channel 20V 4.2A (Tc) 2.5W (Tc) Surface Mount SOT-223

Comment: Looks like a good choice. BTW you could use an N-channel FET if you put it the -ve lead.

Comment: At the end I bought the below one that is matching your requirement. Once I receive it I will test it and let you know the results. Thanks again for your help Bruce.                https://www.fairchildsemi.com/pf/FD/FDN302P.html